# Call second parameter without set first

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters, jquery-plugins

I'm developing a jQuery plugin, and I want to know if there's any possibility to get the second parameter without set the first parameter.

MCVE:

https://jsfiddle.net/2fgb5agL/

```
//jQuery
$.fn.myPlugin = function(param1,param2) {
    return this.each( function() {
        if (param2) {
            alert("param2 ok");
        }
    });
};

//Call the plugin
$("#call").click(function() {
    $(this).myPlugin("", "xyz");
});
```

What I mean is: it's possible to call `$(element).myPlugin("xyz")` and expect the plugin recognize a defined string (ex. "xyz") and then 'do something' (call other function).

So, I don't gonna need to call `$(element).myPlugin(undefined,"xyz")` for get the second param without setting the first one.

Thanks for reading.

p.s.: What I want to achieve is a cleaner code.

Comment: No, there's no way to do what you want, but there are other ways to do this, for instance passing an object, or if the arguments are different, checking if the first argument is some predefined type etc.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the parameter types are strictly different, you can't even create a distinction inside the function.

Is usual to use a single object parameter as argument like so:

```
//jQuery
$.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {
    return this.each( function() {
        if (options.param2) {
            alert("param2 ok");
        }
    });
};

$("#call").click(function() {
    $(this).myPlugin({ param1: "", param2: "xyz" });
});
```

This way you can chose which argument to pass for your plugin. For example: `$(this).myPlugin({ param2: "xyz" });`

Comment: Right, that was my first thought. I tried to avoid the options because passing an object looks kinda ugly. Thank you.

Comment: Well, ugly or not, is the only alternative. And it's also recomended on jQuery's docs (https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/).